# Laravel - Collections. How to separate array into 2 groups

Tags: php, laravel

I have created 2 collections(arrays) which each contain an array of 5 items/events.

```
$events = App\get_event_data( $args )
$collection = collect($events['events']);
$event_chunks = $collection->chunk(5);
$event_chunks->toArray();

@foreach ($event_chunks as $chunk)
```

Output of the above:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[27632]
protected 'items' => 
  array (size=2)
    0 => 
      object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[27630]
        protected 'items' => 
          array (size=5)
            ...
    1 => 
      object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[27631]
        protected 'items' => 
          array (size=5)
            ...
```

In my next loop, it simply goes through every item of the array 1 by 1.
I need to split the 5 items into a further 2 groups:
**group of 2**
**group of 3**
so I can wrap a div around each group.

Current loop:

```
@foreach ($chunk as $key => $event)
    <div class="item">
       {{ $event['title'] }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

What I need:

```
<div class="item-group">
    [item1, item2]
</div>

<div class="item-group">
[item3, item4, item5]
</div>
```

Full code:

```
{{--  Get all events  --}}
@if( $events = App\get_event_data( $args ) )

  @php
    $collection = collect($events['events']);
    $event_chunks = $collection->chunk(5);
    $event_chunks->toArray();
  @endphp

  @foreach ($event_chunks as $chunk)

    <div class="{{ $block }}__flex-grid">

      @foreach ($chunk as $key => $event)
        <div class="item">
          {{ $event['title'] }}
        </div>
      @endforeach

    </div>

  @endforeach

@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you will allways have 5 items, a solution could be:

```
<div class="item-group">
@foreach (array_slice($chunk->toArray(),0,2) as $key => $event)
    <div class="item">
      {{ $event['title'] }}
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
<div class="item-group">
@foreach (array_slice($chunk->toArray(),2) as $key => $event)
    <div class="item">
      {{ $event['title'] }}
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Or if want to avoid code duplication:

```
@php $chunk = [array_slice($chunk->toArray(),0,2), array_slice($chunk,2)];

@foreach ($chunk as $group)
     <div class="item-group">
     @foreach ($group as $key => $event)
         <div class="item">
             {{ $event['title'] }}
         </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

If you don't know or not sure that you have 5, you may need to change the logic of the chunks/slice.

Comment: I am currently getting: `array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`, I dumped $chunk and it is an object array, looking into this now.

Tried `$test = collect($chunk); $test->toArray(); var_dump($test);` but no change.

Comment: It's because `$chunk` is a collection. Updated to use `->toArray()`

Comment: Hey @felippe-duarte. Wondering how I might be able to update the `div class="item-group"` separately? Such as: first group is `div class="item-group--primary"`, second group is `div class="item-group--secondary"`.

Comment: `@foreach ($chunk as $index => $group)` ... `if ($index == 0) -> primary` `if($index==1) --> secondary` ...

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe too late to answer, but I've made a function to split arrays into as groups as you like.

```
function SplitInto($array, $groups = 2)
{
   $members = count($array) / $groups;
   if (count($array) % $groups) $members = (int)(count($array) / $groups) + 1;
   return array_chunk($array, $members);
}
```